# Is it possible to make VICE load .prg files faster?

Tags: commodore-64, emulation, programming

When I load a C64 .prg with the [Hoxs64 emulator](http://www.hoxs64.net/default.aspx), my .prg loads pretty much instantly.

But when I load the same .prg file with VICE (`x64 app.prg`) it takes quite a while (depends on memory map, but several seconds even for compact .prgs).

Is it possible to configure VICE to somehow load .prgs faster?

Comment: Enable warp mode (Alt + W) while loading?

Comment: That could help.  But would be nice if this was automatic.  But looks like I found a way, will post an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting the AutostartPrgMode to value 1 does exactly what I needed.  This will inject the .prg file directly into RAM and basically my app loads instantly.

So:

`x64 -autostartprgmode 1 your_program.prg`

Need to integrate this into my ST3 x64 invocation.

Comment: This is awesome! I updating the options in CBM prg Studio so now my programs load instantly!  Fyi, you need to pre-append `-autostartprgmode 1` to the field Emulator Parameters under Tools > Options > Emulator Control